# Detect last div with class name x and add to it a new class y

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I would like to find out, which is the best way to determine the last div and add a new class to it. Is it javascript or css3?

So here is my example. Let's say I have this:

```
<div class="items">
   <div class="raw">item 1</div>
   <div class="raw">item 2</div>
   <div class="raw">item 3</div>
   <div class="raw">item 4</div>
   <div class="raw">item 5</div>
   <div class="raw">item 6</div>
</div>
```

How? What method? I can add to the last div with class name "raw" a new class name "new"?

so that it will become:

```
<div class="raw new">item 6</div>
```

Comment: You can select the last element easily with CSS, but you can't add a class to it without JavaScript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just:

```
$('div.raw:last').addClass('new');
```

Comment: yeah, if I would look for cross browser solution ill go with this! it works in all browsers... Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can go by pure css:

```
div.raw:last-child {
    /* styles for the last element here */
}
```

or, if you need to be more specific within a child-set

```
div.raw:last-of-type {
    /* styles for the last element here */
}
```

Just in case, the new *class* (*-name*) isn't mandatory.

Both pseudo selectors are compatible with latest W3C browers. IE starting with 9. If you urgently want to support IE7+ I recommend this little lib: https://code.google.com/p/ie7-js/

Comment: :) well then ill go with this solution after 4 years... when IE7/8 will be forgoten! Thank you! I really like this method!

Comment: @AndrewS: unless you're targeting specifically asia or south american regions, IE7/8 pretty much IS forgotten. However, I added a neat little library for legacy support too.

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery as simple as:

```
$(".items > .raw:last").addClass("new");
```

In pure JavaScript with `querySelector`:

```
document.querySelector(".items > .raw:last-child").className += " new";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div.raw:last').addClass('new');
```